# NSException and NSError custom exception/error

Tags: objective-c, exception, nserror, nsexception

I recently started learning Objective-C, and I am working on an iOS app as an exercise, anyway, I want to handle overflow by throwing exception (I come from a Java background), I searched the reference there is only `NSException`, but then I read in the section that say topics about exception handling, and they said to use `NSError`, I read the reference but they had the same protocol and methods, so what's the difference between them? And which is better?

Also, I want to create my own exception or error class, are there any methods or fields that I should include? (Like when implementing the `Exception` interface in Java).
Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`NSError` is designed for non-fatal, recoverable errors. The problems that are designed to be captured by an `NSError` are often *user errors* (or are errors that can be presented to the user), can often be recovered from (hence [`-presentError:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/presentError:) and [`NSErrorRecoveryAttempting`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSErrorRecoveryAttempting_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cat/NSErrorRecoveryAttempting)), and are usually expected or predictable errors (like trying to open a file that you don't have access to, or trying to convert between incompatible string encodings).

`NSException` is designed for potentially fatal, programmer errors. These errors are designed to signify potential flaws in your application where you have not correctly checked the pre-conditions for performing some operations (like trying to access an array index that is beyond its bounds, or attempts to mutate an immutable object). The introduction to the [Exception Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Exceptions.html) explains this a little bit.

Comment: Ohh, Okay.
So for handling overflow I should use Exception, since its a flaw in my application?

Comment: Yes, if its an unexpected situation that should not occur with correct code.

Comment: Ohh Thanks, but what about the second part of the question, creating my own Exception class?

Comment: Subclasses of `NSException` are uncommon: exceptions are typically differentiated by their name (using `+exceptionWithName:reason:userInfo:`), rather than their class. However, you can `@raise` any kind of object as an exception (`NSString`, `NSObject`, anything), there are no special interface requirements (although, this isn't recommended).

Comment: So in this respect, NSError == java checked exception, NSException == Java unchecked exception (RuntimeException)

Comment: No. Objective-C doesn't have checked exceptions, and `NSError` does not trigger exception handlers.

Comment: More like NSError==java unchecked Exception, NSException== java Error